# Intuition behind force components after Lorentz transormations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, reference-frames

So if we have a body that has velocity $v_x=v$ and $v_y=0$ in reference frame $K$ and $v_x'=v_y'=0$ in $K'$. Then if we have force $\vec{F'}$ acting on that body, its components are:
$$F_x=F_x'\\ F_y=\sqrt{1-\beta^2}F_y'$$I know how these formulas are derived but I wonder if you could help me understand them intuitively. For the first one it makes sense that the forces will look the same if we take the increasing mass into account. As the mass increases the acceleration $a_x$ decreases and it is logical that the force stays the same. However I can not seem to understand why the perpendicular component of the force is scaled down by $\gamma$. This means that on top of the lower acceleration due to realtivistic mass there will be even lower accelarion and i can't seem to find intuitive reason why that is the case. Can you explain?

Comment: There cannot be an intuitive understanding. What you are running into is the infamous insanity of the [relativistic, longitudinal and transverse masses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Transverse_and_longitudinal_mass) problem of SR, and the correct way to go is to simply stop dealing with forces. Just talk about energy and momentum transfers, and you will be much less confused.

Answer (score 0):

Perpendicular case:

Alice observes Bob who is bouncing a ball on a spaceship's  side wall. Spaceship moves at speed 0.87 c relative to Alice. Alice says that each bounce transfers a normal amount of momentum but frequency of bounces is reduced to half, so momentum per time is reduced to half, so force is reduced to half.

(momentum in this case = relativistic mass * slowed down speed)

Longitudinal case:

Alice observes Bob who is bouncing a ball on a spaceship's  front wall. Spaceship moves at speed 0.87 c relative to Alice. Alice says that each bounce transfers a double amount of momentum compared to normal, but frequency of bounces is reduced to half, so momentum per time is normal, so force is normal.

(momentum in this case = longitudinal relativistic mass * very much slowed down speed)

(Bob's distance to wall is halved, so average speed of ball is one fourth of the 'normal speed')